# Multiple TypeScript Errors /node_modules/@types when serve Ionic project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I created a new Ionic project just after a new installation of ionic and cordova. When I run `$ionic serve` the browser renders a long list of errors as the image below.

I'm using the next versions:

- Ionic Framework: 3.9.2
- Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.1
- Angular Core: 5.2.11
- Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
- Node: 10.14.2
- OS Platform: macOS

I'll appreciate your help.

[BrowserErrors.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW6Zv.png)

UPDATE:
I've created a new project with Ionic v4 and runs well. Anyway, this issue still happens with Ionic v3 projects.

Comment: Ionic 4 is completely different from ionic 3. you can't run a ionic 3 project with ionic 4 without migrating that project to ionic 4. so it should be a compatibility issue.

Comment: Sure. In fact, I'm considering start the project with Ionic v3 because v4 is beta yet. But as I said, still having this strange issue when I try to run a new project created on Ionic v3.

Comment: Ionic v4 is beta for a while now, I suppose they will release a stable release very soon. you should consider using that.

Answer (score 0):

run `npm install -g ionic@latest` and create a new project and see if you will get the same issue.

Comment: I've tried this and doesn't work. Anyway, i have a curious update: The project runs well with Ionic version 4. Could be kind of compatibility issue?